# How to join 2 detail tables - MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 5 tables naming:

```
tbl_rawmaterial

tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder // master table 1
tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail // detail table 1

tbl_rawmaterialpurchase // master table 2
tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail // detail table 2
```

Now `tbl_rawmaterial` have columns:

```
materialId
materialName
specs
unit
```

And `tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder` have columns:

```
poId
... // and more
```

And `tbl_rawmaterialpurchase` have columns:

```
purchaseId
purchaseorderId
... // and more
```

Detail table `tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail` have columns:

```
id
masterId
itemId
qty
rate
```

Detail table `tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail` have columns:

```
id
masterId
itemId
batchNo
qty
rate
```

this is my query:

```
SELECT
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.id,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.masterId,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.itemId,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.batchNo,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.qty,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.rate,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail.qty AS orderedqty,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterial.specs,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterial.unit
FROM
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchase,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail,
dbname.tbl_rawmaterial
WHERE
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchase.purchaseId = 
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.masterId AND
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder.poId = 
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail.masterId AND
dbname.tbl_rawmaterial.materialId = 
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.itemId AND
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail.itemId = 
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.itemId AND
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail.masterId = 4 AND
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder.poId = 
dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchase.purchaseorderId
```

Before this, data in table

`tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder` and `tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail`

is copied to

`tbl_rawmaterialpurchase` and `tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail`

I tried to use `join` but result comes different.

I need help to convert this into `join`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use inner join.

```
SELECT
  rmpd.id,
  rmpd.masterId,
  rmpd.itemId,
  rmpd.batchNo,
  rmpd.qty,
  rmpd.rate,
  rmpod.qty AS orderedqty,
  rm.specs,
  rm.unit
FROM dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchase rmp 
  INNER JOIN dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchasedetail rmpd ON rmp.purchaseId = rmpd.masterId
  INNER JOIN dbname.tbl_rawmaterial rm ON rmpd.itemId = rm.materialId
  INNER JOIN dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorder rmpo ON rmp.purchaseorderId = rmpo.poId
  INNER JOIN dbname.tbl_rawmaterialpurchaseorderdetail rmpod ON (rmpo.poId = rmpod.masterId AND rmpod.itemId = rmpd.itemId)
WHERE
  rmpd.masterId = 4
```

Side note: It is better you use alias for tables so the query is more readable.

Comment: Thanks You So Much. You Are Genius!